# Select the same option twice using chosen.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I've been working with the jQuery Plugin called Chosen.js,  I'm wondering if there is a way to select two of the same options, for example: Right now if you have a multiple selection box, you can select as many options as you want and they get added to the select box, but each option you select gets greyed out, is there a way to not make that option greyed out so you can select it again?  I've looked through the documentation and I can't seem to find my answer, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it should go by value, so if you give two same-text options two different values, both should be independently select-able, unless you found a bug.

Comment: Haha, that's my problem.  I need the value to be the same.

Comment: @WilliamL. have you have found a solution to this? I'm struggling with this problem myself